# Initialize Vault on Jboss 6.4, Exception: PBOX000137

Tags: keystore, jboss6.x

I am trying to initialize the Vault on JBoss 6.4 using the below redhat tutorial:

My environment is:

- Windows 10
- java version "1.8.0_211" 
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12) 
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
- Jboss EAP 6.4

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/security_guide/mask_the_keystore_password_and_initialize_the_password_vault.

but I get the below error:

`Initializing Vault
Exception encountered:Exception encountered:java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000137: Security Vault does not contain SecretKey entry under alias (vault)`

**------- Update ------**

When I try to initialize it with the below commands: (vault directory is inside bin folder, I tried both absolute and relative path, same exception)

```
jboss-eap-6.4\bin\vault.bat --keystore vault/vault.keystore --keystore-password vault22 --alias vault --vault-block ds_irdb --attribute password --sec-attr IRM%bph2018 --enc-dir vault --iteration 120 --salt asdfghjk


jboss-eap-6.4\bin\vault.bat --keystore vault\vault.keystore --keystore-password vault22 --alias vault --vault-block ds_irdb --attribute password --sec-attr somePassword --enc-dir vault\ --iteration 120 --salt asdfghjk
```

I get the below exception:

```
java.io.ObjectInputStream filterCheck
INFO: ObjectInputFilter REJECTED: null, array length: -1, nRefs: 1, depth: 1, bytes: 70, ex: n/a
Problem occured:
java.lang.Exception: Exception encountered:java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore (vault/vault.keystore)
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.VaultSession.initSecurityVault(VaultSession.java:194)
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.VaultSession.startVaultSession(VaultSession.java:212)
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.VaultTool.execute(VaultTool.java:196)
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.VaultTool.main(VaultTool.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:473)
Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore (vault/vault.keystore)
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:210)
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.VaultSession.initSecurityVault(VaultSession.java:191)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore (vault/vault.keystore)
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:691)
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:205)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:856)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:201)
        at org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:151)
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:688)
```

What I have missed here?

I think it is related to the last line of exception `Invalid secret key format` and I have read in redhat bug list that it is related to Java 8 cryptography package.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of struggling with this issue, I found that it is a bug in JBoss 6.4.

the resolution exist in redhat on the below address:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1569958

The summary of the above page (it needs redhat account to see the result) is that you need to add the below line:

`<module name="sun.jdk"/>`

in the dependencies in the file:

`jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\module.xml`

It is disappointing that after days no response was received here!